# редирект и статус код

Tags: php, синтаксис

Синтаксис команды редиректа

```
header("Location: http://www.example.com/",status_code);
```

В поле status_code можно указать 301, 302, 303. 
На чем основан выбор? Какой критерий выборки?

Answer (score 1):

В [википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_HTTP#301) сказано

**301 Moved Permanently — запрошенный документ был окончательно перенесен на новый URI**, указанный в поле Location заголовка. Некоторые клиенты некорректно ведут себя при обработке данного кода. Появился в HTTP/1.0.

**302 Found, 302 Moved Temporarily — запрошенный документ временно доступен по другому URI,** указанному в заголовке в поле Location. Этот код может быть использован, например, при управляемом сервером согласовании содержимого. Некоторые клиенты некорректно ведут себя при обработке данного кода. Введено в HTTP/1.0.

**303 See Other — документ по запрошенному URI нужно запросить по адресу в поле Location заголовка с использованием метода GET несмотря даже на то, что первый запрашивался иным методом**. Этот код был введён вместе с 307-ым для избежания неоднозначности, чтобы сервер был уверен, что следующий ресурс будет запрошен методом GET. Например, на веб-странице есть поле ввода текста для быстрого перехода и поиска. После ввода данных браузер делает запрос методом POST, включая в тело сообщения введённый текст. Если обнаружен документ с введённым названием, то сервер отвечает кодом 303, указав в заголовке Location его постоянный адрес. Тогда браузер гарантировано его запросит методом GET для получения содержимого. В противном случае сервер просто вернёт клиенту страницу с результатами поиска. Введено в HTTP/1.1.

Answer (score 1):

Для пользователя это не имеет никакого значения. Тут нужно думать о поисковиках, так как редиректы влияют на так называемый ссылочный вес, от которого зависит продвижение сайта.

- 301 - страница перемещена навсегда.
- 302 - страница перемещена временно и скоро вернется на место.
- 303 - практически не используется.

Если у вас редиректы происходят внутри сайта, то используй 302 редирект - ничего не потеряете.